# NoReverseMatch at /plat/salade-nicoise/

Tags: python, django

I hope you're well.

It's probably a very simple question but:

- if I name my Catego "exemple" and if I give "exemple" to the same of the slug, anything works
- if I name my Catego "Salade Nicoise" and if I give "salade-nicoise" to the same of the slug, I've the issue:

**Reverse for 'post_catego' with arguments '('salade nicoise',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['plat/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']**

So if the name of the slug and the catego are the same it works, but if not it does not works.

Could someone explain to me why that works like?

views.py

```
def catego(request, slug):
    catego = Catego.objects.get(slug=slug)
    
    context = {
        'catego': catego
    }
```

models.py

```
class Catego(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='nocategory')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Catego', related_name='posts')
```

urls.py

```
path('plat/<slug:slug>/', catego, name="post_catego"),
```

post_catego.html

```
{% for post in catego.posts.all %}
...
{% for catego in post.categories.all %} <a href="{% url 'post_catego' catego.name %}">&#128154; {{ catego.name }}</a>{% endfor %}
...
{% enfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're well too.

It has probably a very simple answer
in your post_catego.html when passing the url value put catego.slug instead of catego.name.

post_catego.html

```
{% for post in catego.posts.all %}
...
{% for catego in post.categories.all %} <a href="{% url 'post_catego' catego.slug %}">&#128154; {{ catego.name }}</a>{% endfor %}
...
{% enfor %}
```